# AngularJS and dojox.charting - 'nodeType' of null"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dojo, angularjs-directive

I am attempting to populate a repeating (ng-repeat) div with different graphs from Dojo based on the current data model.

When my code runs I get  the error "Cannot read property 'nodeType' of null"

I believe this is because dojo is attempting to render into a div that has not actually been created yet. It exists in memory and AngularJS can work with it but has not been created in the dom.

This is the code I am using.

How can I ensure that the element has been created?

```
function GetBarChart(elementName)
{
require(["dojox/charting/Chart", "dojox/charting/axis2d/Default", "dojox/charting/plot2d/StackedAreas", "dojox/charting/themes/Wetland" , "dojo/ready"],
  function(Chart, Default, StackedAreas, Wetland, ready)
 {

ready(function()
{
  alert(elementName);
  var c = new Chart(elementName);
  c.addPlot("default", {type: StackedAreas, tension:3})
    .addAxis("x", {fixLower: "major", fixUpper: "major"})
    .addAxis("y", {vertical: true, fixLower: "major", fixUpper: "major", min: 0})
    .setTheme(Wetland)
    .addSeries("Series A", [1, 2, 0.5, 1.5, 1, 2.8, 0.4])
    .addSeries("Series B", [2.6, 1.8, 2, 1, 1.4, 0.7, 2])
    .addSeries("Series C", [6.3, 1.8, 3, 0.5, 4.4, 2.7, 2])
    .render();
});
});

}

angular.module('myApp')
.directive('myWidget', function() 
{
return {
 link:function(scope, element, attrs)
 {      
    element.id = scope.widget.id;
    GetBarChart(element.id );
    console.log(element);
  }
};
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still new to AngualJS but a solution was to set the id of the div in the directive html rather than setting it in the link function

```
<div id ="{{widget.id}}" ></div>
```

not

```
element.id = scope.widget.id;
```

This seems to have removed the ordering problems.

But I wonder if there is yet another better way.

Answer (score -1):

element is wrapped by jQuery, if you want to get the id, you should write like this:

```
element[0].id
```

Comment: There is no mention of jQuery in this question and I see no evidence of it in the code.